# Read values from .val() object in firebase linked app?

Tags: javascript, object, reactjs, firebase

I am working on a simple to do application linked to firebase using react native, I am facing a problem when I wanna render the information.
my render method looks something like this:

```
  renderRow(rowData) {
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight
      underlayColor='#dddddd'
      onPress={() => this.removeTodo(rowData)}>
      <View>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.todoText}>{rowData.text}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.separator} />
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}
```

problem is that this is an object `rowData.text` and not a string as it should be

this is part of my method for pushing the info to firebase:

```
this.itemsRef.on('child_added', (dataSnapshot) => {
      this.items.push({id: dataSnapshot.key(), text: dataSnapshot.val()});
      this.setState({
        todoSource: this.state.todoSource.cloneWithRows(this.items)
      });
    });
```

firebase documentation only states that .val()  may return a primitive (string, number, or boolean), an array, or an object. It may also return null. I know that in my case it's returning an object, but I don't know why, nor how to change it to string?

Edit: 
Here's the class i am working on:

```
class ToDo_React extends Component {
  // Your App Code
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase('https://resplendent-heat-7859.firebaseio.com');
      this.itemsRef = myFirebaseRef.child('items');

      this.state = {
      newTodo: '',
      todoSource: new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2})
      };

      this.items = [];
      }
      componentDidMount() {
    // When a todo is added
    this.itemsRef.on('child_added', (dataSnapshot) => {
      this.items.push({id: dataSnapshot.key(), text: dataSnapshot.val()});
      this.setState({
        todoSource: this.state.todoSource.cloneWithRows(this.items)
      });
    });

    // When a todo is removed
    this.itemsRef.on('child_removed', (dataSnapshot) => {
        this.items = this.items.filter((x) => x.id !== dataSnapshot.key());
        this.setState({
          todoSource: this.state.todoSource.cloneWithRows(this.items)
        });
    });
  }
  addTodo() {
if (this.state.newTodo !== '') {
this.itemsRef.push({
  todo: this.state.newTodo
});
this.setState({
  newTodo : ''
});
}
}
removeTodo(rowData) {
this.itemsRef.child(rowData.id).remove();
}
        removeTodo(rowData) {
      this.itemsRef.child(rowData.id).remove();
    }
    render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.appContainer}>
      <View style={styles.titleView}>
        <Text style={styles.titleText}>
          My Todos
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputcontainer}>
        <TextInput style={styles.input} onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({newTodo: text})} value={this.state.newTodo}/>
        <TouchableHighlight
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => this.addTodo()}
          underlayColor='#dddddd'>
          <Text style={styles.btnText}>Add!</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.todoSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)} />
    </View>
  );
}
renderRow(rowData) {
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight
      underlayColor='#dddddd'
      onPress={() => this.removeTodo(rowData)}>
      <View>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.todoText}>{rowData.text}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.separator} />
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}
}
```

Comment: What does the JSON for an item look like? For example when you console.log(snapshot.val())?

Comment: no message is displayed in the console when i add the console log

Comment: Check the Firebase reference's URL. If you're getting an object back you might need to go one level deeper to get the property that has the primitive value.

Comment: i only have level in the DB "item", that doesn't seem to work

Comment: Can you post your data structure and how you construct `this.itemRef`?

Comment: @DavidEast I have added the entire class to the question for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're using ListView's DataSource wrong. I may be wrong, but I don't think you're suppose to override your initial `ListView.DataSource` instance. Give this a go.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase('https://resplendent-heat-7859.firebaseio.com');
  this.itemsRef = myFirebaseRef.child('items');
  this.items = [];
  this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2})

  this.state = {
    newTodo: '',
    todoSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows([])
  };

}
componentDidMount() {
  this.itemsRef.on('child_added', (dataSnapshot) => {
    this.items.push({id: dataSnapshot.key(), text: dataSnapshot.val()});
    this.setState({
      todoSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.items)
    });
  });

  this.itemsRef.on('child_removed', (dataSnapshot) => {
    this.items = this.items.filter((x) => x.id !== dataSnapshot.key());
    this.setState({
      todoSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.items)
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you didn't figure this one out, you have to add val().todo to make this work. I added more code so that ListView will render on initial load. Hope this helps!

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
     todoSource: this.state.todoSource
    });

    // When a todo is added
    this.itemsRef.on('child_added', (dataSnapshot) => {
     this.items.push({id: dataSnapshot.key(), text: dataSnapshot.val().todo});
     this.setState({
      todoSource: this.state.todoSource.cloneWithRows(this.items)
   });
});
```